# What's lewd about 'associated primes'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

[Number 6 of this poster on Maths SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1103355) implies some smutty subtext or wordplay for the noun phrase 'associated primes', which I fail to perceive, so would someone please explain and reveal the bawdiness?

> [image]

Comment: Because of its notation with "Ass".

Comment: @StoneyB I espy it now! Thanks. I didn't realise that the mathematical notation, and not the noun phrase, was ribald!

Comment: It isn't just the Ass notation - it is that R(M) looks a little like "rim."

Comment: also, the `(M)` kinda looked like an Ass(it looked more like that in the picture posted in the answer than it does here)

Comment: Though I still don't see what's supposed to be naughty about "nilpotent unit".

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't perceive the wordplay perfectly either, but my guess is that it concerns the absence of reproductive potency, as implied by 'nil'? 'Nilpotent unit' = Impotent (reproductive) unit?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit: Got it.  And *unit* can be [slang for *penis*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=unit&defid=202524).

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you! However, beware that I was only guessing; please question my guess. I didn't know about that insinuation of *unit*; I thought that that was another inference for the reader. In fact, now that we're discussing #7, what's the wordplay behind 'Idempotent unit'? That one's potency is identical to someone else's? How is this funny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind this is the notion with Ass, not only that but the R(M) Looks like a rim.

Hope this helps.